# Is it "Enterprise Team" or "Enterprise team" and "IT Support" or "IT support"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, proper-nouns, capitalization

I'm a bit confused regarding capitalizing certain words as I have found both their capitalized and uncapitalized forms on the Internet; for example, consider the following sentences:

> "*Collaborate with the Enterprise Team in a timely manner.*"
>
> "*Collaborate with the Enterprise team in a timely manner.*"
>
> "*Provide courteous IT Support.*"
>
> "*Provide courteous IT support.*"

Will it be "Enterprise Team" or "Enterprise team" and "IT Support" or "IT support". A little explanation will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely not capitalize “support” in this context and probably would not capitalize “team” either. If the word is not part of the name, don’t capitalize it. “IT Support” could be capitalized if it were the name of a department (e.g. “Please contact IT Support”)- in your example it is not being used as a name, so it doesn’t require capitalization of the word “support”. “IT” will always be capitalized because it is a standard abbreviation.